# Script Error message when uploading images

Tags: configuration

We are facing script error while trying to upload images to one of the News archive web part in the share point site
The error says " An error has occurred in the script on this page"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps to fix this typical browser related issue caused by improper scripting on the web page.

1. To resolve this issue, follow these steps on remedy side: Close all
   the open browser windows.
2. Navigate to the temp folder on the local machine. Generally located at C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Local Settings\Temp Delete all the temp files
3. Restart the system if needed
4. Open the browser and try to reproduce the error

Answer (score 1):

The error is too generic and require more information to catch the root cause of issue.

First thing is to restart the browser.

Secondly debugging the issue. This can be achieved in many ways.

1. Enable script debugging option in browser. Then after refresh you
   will get an option to debug in the IDE that is available in your
   machine.
2. If you have Developer Tool bar available in your browser then the
   Console window will give you more information about the error like
   line number etc.